# Capture two variables in liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

#### What I want to do:

Capture two variables `{{section.settings.{{title}}_modal_title}}`

#### Context:

The links in the linklist are not really used as links, but purely so user can reorganize it in their Shopify portal.
External javascript file creates elements (modals) on click event, value from `section.settings.XXX_modal_title` is supposed to be used in the created modals.

The linklist:

```
<ul class="menu">
            {% for link in linklists.main-menu.links %}
                <li data-menu="{{ link.title | upcase }}" class="menu-link">
                    <p class="menu-title">[{{ link.title | upcase }}]</p> <-- Click event
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

#### What I tried:

- My first try was adding the liquid tag itself with `.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',` {{section.settings.${attLowerCase}_modal_title}}`)` when the element is created, but soon realized that liquid renders the values first. The output of doing this is literally "{{  }}"
- My second try was to capture two variables and put it in a hidden input.

```
{% assign title = link.title | downcase %}
                    {% capture section_title_variable %}
                        {{section.settings.{{title}}_modal_settings}}
                    {% endcapture %}
                    <hr class="item-line">
                    <p class="ueq-menu-title">[{{ link.title | upcase }}]</p>
                    <input type="hidden" id="about_modal_title" value="{{section_title_variable}}">
```

#### In depth example:

```
section.settings

{
            "type": "text",
            "id": "about_modal_title",
            "label": "About window title",
            "default": "ABOUT"
},
```

- User clicks on link ABOUT

```
<ul class="menu">
            {% for link in linklists.ueq-menu.links %}
                <li data-menu="{{ link.title | upcase }}" class="menu-link"> <-- "ABOUT"

                    {% assign title = link.title | downcase %} <-- downcase to "about"
                    {% capture section_title_variable %}
                        {{section.settings.{{title}}_modal_title}}
                        
                    {% endcapture %}
                    <hr class="item-line">
                    <p class="menu-title">[{{ link.title | upcase }}]</p>
                    <input type="hidden" id="about_modal_title" value="{{section_title_variable}}"> <-- captured should look like this {{section.settings.about_modal_title}}


                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

- on click event, get the value from hidden input, and use it when creating elements.

#### "Why not use `{% javascript %}`?"

I prefer to do it this way, since most of my script files are external. I like to keep it that way.

#### "Why capture it like that?"

The links in the linklist are already known, this was in the design. Thats why in sechema one of them is called "about_modal_title". Since this is used inside a for loop, this was the only way I could come up with to connect the title and schema settings with each other.

If someone knows a better way to do this instead of putting it in a hidden input, please let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In proper Liquid syntax, curly-brackets are never embedded inside curly-brackets

The syntax `{{ something_{{ you }}_want }}` is illegal Liquid syntax - once an expression is started, using either `{{` or `{%`, everything up to the next `}}` or `%}` is evaluated as one template command.

In your example, you're looking to combine two strings in order to get the name of a setting that you want to access. In a dedicated programming language, we would expect there to be nice shortcuts for something like this. Liquid, however, is first and foremost a *templating* language, and doesn't have such shortcuts. Instead, we will need to accomplish our goal in two steps.

The first thing we need to know is that we can access properties in two ways: `{{ settings.fieldname }}` is equivalent to `{{ settings['fieldname'] }}`

Thanks to that second syntax, we can access an arbitrary setting using a variable:

```
{% assign field = 'fieldname' %}
{{ settings[fieldname] }}
```

So to do something more complicated, we just need to use `assign` (or `capture` - just be aware that capture includes whitespace as well!) to get a variable that contains the name of the field we want to access, then pass that in to the square brackets:

```
{% assign title_field = link.title | downcase | append: '_modal_title' %}
{{ section.settings[title_field] }}
```