# Liquid variable holds metafield path but does not work in img src

Tags: shopify, liquid

I need to display one of four random images that are URLs in metafields in Shopify so must use a variable as the img src.

```
{%- assign min = 1 -%}
{%- assign max = 4 -%}
{%- assign diff = max | minus: min -%}
{%- assign random_number = "now" | date: "%N" | modulo: diff | plus: min -%}

{% capture image %}
pages["explore-more-ingredients"].metafields.global.explore_ingredients_image{{ random_number}}.value
{% endcapture %}
```

So I take that image variable and look at how each of these items below is presented in the browser (image attached)

```
1. {{ image }} <br>
2. {{ pages["explore-more-ingredients"].metafields.global.explore_ingredients_image2.value }} <br>
3. <img src="{{ image }}">
4. <img src="{{ pages["explore-more-ingredients"].metafields.global.explore_ingredients_image2.value }}">
```

What am I doing wrong? Need number 3 to work since URLs are generated randomly. Is this a syntax issue?

When I look at the source code of how 3 is rendered in browser it says `<img src="pages[" explore-more-ingredients"].metafields.global.explore_ingredients_image3.value"="">`

Thank you for guidance.

[image]

Comment: I had another answer that addressed the syntax error here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70293919/capture-two-variables-in-liquid/70296735#70296735  In short, we never nest template brackets inside template brackets when using Liquid.  You should just need to `assign` your metafield key to a variable and then access that using the square-bracket notation. :)

Answer (score 0):

generate an array with all the pictures.

generate random number within the boundary of all the pictures

display the picture with the random number.

```
{% assign images= pages["explore-more-ingredients"].metafields.global.explore_ingredients_image2.value | append: " | " | append: image2 | append: " | " | append: image3 | split: " | " %}

{% assign min = 0 %}
{% assign max = images | size %}
{% assign diff = max | minus: min %}
{% assign randomNumber = "now" | date: "%N" | modulo: diff | plus: min %}

<img src="{{images[randomNumber]}}" />
```